# Possible to hide / remove custom title bar programatically, after creation?

Tags: android, show-hide, titlebar, custom-titlebar

What I'm trying to do is hide a custom title bar when the user edits text in my app, so as to give him a wider view.  I can blank the elements inside the title bar just fine but that just makes empty space; I am trying to make the app window expand to take advantage of that space dynamically.

I've already setup a custom title bar, which is integral to the navigation of my app.  It allows the user to jump between fragments.  I am only trying to temporarily hide the title bar.

I am using the following custom theme:

```
<style name="GTTheme2" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">37dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

In my activity I have.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.gtDisplay);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
R.layout.custom_title_gt_phone);
```

I have tried the following

```
 getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
```

That returns a null pointer exception because the action bar doesn't exist because I set up a custom title.  I tried setting "Android:windowActionBar" to true my theme, but apparently the setting conflicts with setting up a custom title bar, as my app failed to load.

I also tried

```
getActivity().setTheme( <<some new theme here>>);
```

Where the new theme didn't have a title or had 0dp for windowTitleSize, but screen didn't change.

Tried searching if there is a way to set windowTitleSize dynamically (other than as a startup theme in AndroidMainfest) but haven't found anything.  Any thoughts?

Comment: did you try this\\\ requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);